# Partial sums with a twist (adding up to the previous element)

Tags: ruby

I have an array of integers, say

```
a=[4, 6, 7, 2]
```

and I would like to produce a new array of the same size, with the following properties:

```
- The first array, b[0], is 0
- For the remaining elements, b[n] is the sum of all elements from a[0] up to a[n].
```

Hence, for `a` above, `b` should turn out as `[0, 4, 10, 17]`.

Efficiency is not an issue (although I would like to reuse already caluclated partial sums, instead recalculate them again and again), but the result should be understandable in maintaiable.

I came up with the following solution:

```
b=[nil]*a.size
ind=-1
b.map! {|i| (ind >= 0 ? (a[ind]+b[ind]) : 0).tap {ind+=1}};
```

This works, but I don't like it much, mostly because of the "backindex" variable `ind` and the need to preallocate `b`. I would like to have something like

```
b = a.map{ .... }
```

or similar. Does anybody have some idea of how to do it better?

Comment: There's `map.with_index` which moves that functionality to existing code.

Comment: @DaveNewton : I thought about it, but I would have then to calculate the one-off index inside the block, i.e. `a.map_with_index {|i| ind=i-1;....}`.

Comment: @Matt : Your solution is great!!!! Please make it an answer, and I will accept it. I just suggest renaming the block parameter `a` to, say, `memo` to avoid a warning that the local variable `a` is shadowing the outer variable `a` (if `$VERBOSE` is turned on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [inject](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/inject):

```
a.inject([0]) { |acc,x| acc << acc.last + x }
=> [0, 4, 10, 17, 19]
```

and then `pop` off the last element, from either the result or `a` before the call.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it looks weird because you should call the input array inside the loop:

```
a.each_with_object([]).with_index do |(_, array), index|
  array << (index.zero? ? 0 : array[index - 1] + a[index - 1])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The general operation is called [*prefix sum* or *scan*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), and is available in [many collection libraries](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterable.html#scanLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):CC[B]) … unfortunately not in Ruby's. There are some third-party gems that extend Ruby's collection libraries that have it, but it is not *too* hard to roll your own:

```rb
module EnumerableScanExtension
  def scan(init)
    return enum_for(__callee__) unless block_given?

    inject([[init], init]) do |(res, acc), el|
      acc = yield acc, el
      [res << acc, acc]
    end.first
  end
end

module EnumerableWithScan
  refine Enumerable do
    include EnumerableScanExtension
  end
end

using EnumerableWithScan

[4, 6, 7, 2].scan(0) {|acc, el| acc + el }
#=> [0, 4, 10, 17, 19]
```

[Note: Ideally, the implementation should fully mimic all the modes and overloads of `inject`; I left that out for brevity.]

Your desired result is then just a slight modification:

```rb
[4, 6, 7, 2].scan(0) {|acc, el| acc + el }[0...-1]
#=> [0, 4, 10, 17]
```

Comment: An alternative would be to replace `inject([[], init])` with `inject([[init], init])`, in which case `[4, 6, 7, 2].scan(10) {|acc, el| acc + el } #=> [10, 14, 20, 27, 29]` (rather than `[14, 20, 27, 29]`). I'm thinking that `init` would most often be wanted as the first element (which could always be `drop(1)`ed). An example would be when the method is used to convert a discrete PDF (probability density function) to a CDF (with `1.0` appended). One might also consider giving `init` a default value of zero.

Comment: Yes, that would bring it more in line with what other languages are doing. Ideally, it would implement the full protocol of `inject` but doing that in Ruby is [incredibly annoying](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerable.rb#L370-L403) without method overloading or privileged internal access to the arguments list.

Comment: Great idea for a general solution, to enhance our library. For my concrete case, I feel that using `incject` directly, as proposed by Matt in his comment, is simpler and very readable.

Comment: There is a feature request to add such a method to Ruby https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17016 but the core team wants to be sure if it's useful