# Ruby equivalent of Python's dict comprehension

Tags: ruby

I'm rewriting a Python project to Ruby.

This is a pure Ruby project, so there's no framework, such as Rails attached to it.

Project has a lot of dictionary comprehension all over the place.

For example:

```py
original = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}

squares = {name:value**2 for (name,value) in original.items()}
print(squares)
```

The closest thing I got in Ruby is:

```rb
original = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

squares = original.inject ({}) do | squared, (name,value) | 
  squared[name] = value ** 2;
  squared
end 
puts squares
```

This obviously works, but I wondered if there's more convenient or more readable way to write this in Ruby.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's take a couple of steps back and ignore the specifics of Ruby and Python for now.

## Mathematical set-builder notation

The concept of *comprehension* originally comes from [mathematical *set-builder notation*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation), e.g. something like this: **E = { n ∈ ℕ | 2∣n }** which defines **E** to be the set of all even natural numbers, as does **E = { 2n | n ∈ ℕ }**.

## List comprehensions in Programming Languages

This set-builder notation inspired similar constructs in many programming languages all the way back to 1969, although it wasn't until the 1970s that Phil Wadler coined the term *comprehensions* for these. [*List comprehensions*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) ended up being implemented in Miranda in the early 1980s, which was a hugely influential programming language.

However, it is important to understand that these comprehensions *do not* add any new semantic features to the world of programming languages. In general, there is no program you can write with a comprehension that you cannot also write without. Comprehensions provide a *very convenient syntax* for expressing these kinds of transformations, but they don't do anything that couldn't also be achieved with the standard *recursion patterns* like [*fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)), [*map*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)), [*scan*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Scan_higher_order_function), [*unfold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Unfold_(higher-order_function)), and friends.

So, let's first look at how [the various features of Python's comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) compare to the standard recursion patterns, and then see how those recursion patterns are available in Ruby.

## Python

[Note: I will use Python list comprehension syntax here, but it doesn't really matter since list, set, dict comprehensions and generator expressions all work the same. I will also use the convention from functional programming to use single-letter variables for collection elements and the plural for collections, i.e. `x` for an element and `xs` for "a collection of x-es".]

### Transforming each element the same way

```python
[f(x) for x in xs]
```

This *transforms* each element of the original collection using a transformation function into a new element of a new collection. This new collection has the same number of elements as the original collection and there is a 1:1 correspondence between the elements of the original collection and the elements of the new collection.

One could say that each element of the original collection is *mapped* to an element of the new collection. Hence, this is typically called *map* in many programming languages, and in fact, [it is called that in Python as well](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map):

```python
map(f, xs)
```

### The same, but nested

Python allows you to have multiple `for` / `in`s in a single comprehension. This is more or less equivalent to having *nested* mappings which then get *flattened* into a single collection:

```python
[f(x, y) for x in xs for y in ys]
# or
[f(y) for ys in xs for y in ys]
```

This combination of *mapping* and then *flattening* the collection is commonly known as [*flatMap* (when applied to collections) or *bind* (when applied to Monads)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Definition).

### Filtering

The last operation that Python comprehensions support is *filtering*:

```python
[x for x in xs if p(x)]
```

This will filter the collection `xs` into a collection which contains a subset of the original elements which satisfy the predicate `p`. This operation is commonly known as *filter*.

### Combine as you like

Obviously, you can combine all of these, i.e. you can have a comprehension with multiple nested generators that filter out some elements and then transform them.

## Ruby

Ruby also provides all of the *recursion patterns* (or *collection operations*) mentioned above, and many more. In Ruby, an object that can be iterated over, is called an *enumerable*, and the [`Enumerable` mixin in the core library](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) provides a lot of useful and powerful collection operations.

Ruby was originally heavily inspired by Smalltalk, and some of the older names of Ruby's original collection operations still go back to this Smalltalk heritage. In the Smalltalk collections framework, there is an in-joke about all the collections methods rhyming with each other, thus, the fundamental collections method in Smalltalk are called [listed here with their more standard equivalents from functional programming]:

- `collect:`, which "collects" all elements returned from a block into a new collection, i.e. this is the equivalent to *map*.
- `select:`, which "selects" all elements that satisfy a block, i.e. this is the equivalent to *filter*.
- `reject:`, which "rejects" all elements that satisfy a block, i.e. this is the opposite of `select:` and thus equivalent to what is sometimes called *filterNot*.
- `detect:`, which "detects" whether an element which satisfies a block is inside the collection, i.e. this is the equivalent to *contains*. Except, it actually returns the element as well, so it is more like *findFirst*.
- `inject:into:` … where the nice naming schema breaks down somewhat …: it *does* "inject" a starting value "into" a block but that's a somewhat strained connection to what it actually does. This is the equivalent to *fold*.

So, Ruby has all of those, and more, and it uses some of the original naming, but thankfully, it also provides aliases.

### Map

In Ruby, *map* is originally named [`Enumerable#collect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect) but is also available as [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), which is the name preferred by most Rubyists.

As mentioned above, this is also available in Python as the `map` built-in function.

### FlatMap

In Ruby, *flatMap* is originally named [`Enumerable#collect_concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-collect_concat) but is also available as [`Enumerable#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), which is the name preferred by most Rubyists.

### Filter

In Ruby, *filter* is originally named [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-select), which is the name preferred by most Rubyists, but is also available as [`Enumerable#find_all`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all).

### FilterNot

In Ruby, *filterNot* is named [`Enumerable#reject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject).

### FindFirst

In Ruby, *findFirst* is originally named [`Enumerable#detect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect), but is also available as [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find).

### Fold

In Ruby, *fold* is originally named [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), but is also available as [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

It also exists in Python as [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

### Unfold

In Ruby, *unfold* is named [`Enumerator::produce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-c-produce).

### Scan

*Scan* is [unfortunately not available in Ruby](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/17016). It *is* available in Python as [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate).

## A deep dive into recursion patterns

Armed with our nomenclature from above, we now know that what you wrote is called a *fold*:

```ruby
squares = original.inject ({}) do |squared, (name, value)| 
  squared[name] = value ** 2
  squared
end
```

What you wrote here works. And that sentence I just wrote is actually surprisingly deep! Because *fold* has a very powerful property: **everything which can be expressed as iterating over a collection can be expressed as a fold**. In other words, everything that can be expressed as recursing over a collection (in a functional language), everything that can be expressed as looping / iterating over a collection (in an imperative language), everything that can be expressed using any of the afore-mentioned functions (*map*, *filter*, *find*), everything that can be expressed using Python's comprehensions, everything that can be expressed using some of the additional functions we haven't discussed yet (e.g. *groupBy*) can by expressed using *fold*.

If you have *fold*, you don't need anything else! If you were to remove every method from `Enumerable` except `Enumerable#inject`, you could still write everything you could write before; you could actually re-implement all the methods you just removed only by using `Enumerable#inject`. In fact, [I did that once for fun as an exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3834035/2988). You could also [implement the missing *scan* operation mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62176672/2988).

It is not necessarily obvious that *fold* really is general, but think of it this way: a collection can be either empty or not. *fold* has two arguments, one which tells it what to do when the collection is empty, and one which tells it what to do when the collection is not empty. Those are the only two cases, so every possible case is handled. Therefore, *fold* can do everything!

Or a different viewpoint: a collection is a stream of instructions, either the `EMPTY` instruction or the `ELEMENT(value)` instruction. *fold* is a skeleton *interpreter* for that instruction set, and you as a programmer can supply the implementation for the interpretation of both those instructions, namely the two arguments to *fold* *are* the interpretation of those instructions. [I was introduced to this eye-opening interpretation of *fold* as an interpreter and a collection as an instruction stream is due to [Rúnar Bjarnason](https://twitter.com/runarorama), co-author of [*Functional Programming in Scala*](https://manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) and co-designer of the [Unison Programming Language](https://unisonweb.org/). Unfortunately, I cannot find the original talk anymore, but [*The Interpreter Pattern Revisited*](https://youtu.be/hmX2s3pe_qk) presents a much more general idea that should also bring it across.]

Note that the way you are using *fold* here is somewhat awkward, because you are using *mutation* (i.e. a side-effect) for an operation that is deeply rooted in functional programming. *Fold* uses the return value of one iteration as the starting value for the next iteration. But the operation you are doing is a *mutation* which doesn't actually return a useful value for the next iteration. That's why you have to then return the accumulator which you just modified.

If you were to express this in a functional way using [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge), without mutation, it would look cleaner:

```ruby
squares = original.inject ({}) do |squared, (name, value)| 
  squared.merge({ name => value ** 2})
end
```

However, for the *specific* use-case where instead of returning a *new* accumulator on each iteration and using that for the next iteration, you want to just *mutate* the *same* accumulator over and over again, Ruby offers a different variant of *fold* under the name [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), which completely *ignores* the return value of the block and just passes the same accumulator object every time. Confusingly, the order of the arguments in the block is reversed between `Enumerable#inject` (accumulator first, element second) and `Enumerable#each_with_object` (element first, accumulator second):

```ruby
squares = original.each_with_object ({}) do |(name, value), squared| 
  squared[name] = value ** 2}
end
```

However, it turns out, we can make this even simpler. I explained above that *fold* is general, i.e. it can solve every problem. Then why do we have those other operations in the first place? We have them for the same reason that we have subroutines, conditionals, exceptions, and loops, even though we could do everything with just `GOTO`: *expressivity*.

If you read some code using only `GOTO`, you have to "reverse engineer" what every particular usage of `GOTO` means: is it checking a condition, is it doing something multiple times? By having different, more specialized constructs, you can recognize at a glance what a particular piece of code does.

The same applies to these collection operations. In your case, for example, you are transforming each element of the original collection into a new element of the result collection. But, you have to actually read and understand what the block does, in order to recognize this.

However, as we discussed above, there is a *more specialized* operation available which does this: *map*. And everybody who sees *map* immediately understands "oh, this is mapping each element 1:1 to a new element", without having to even look at what the block does. So, we can write your code like this instead:

```ruby
squares = original.map do |name, value| 
  [name, value ** 2]
end.to_h
```

Note: Ruby's collection operations are for the most part not *type-preserving*, i.e. transforming a collection will typically not yield the same type of collection. Instead, in general, collection operations mostly return [`Array`s](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html), which is why we have to call [`Array#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Arra.html#method-i-to_h) here at the end.

As you can see, because this operation is more specialized than *fold* (which can do everything), it is both simpler to read and also simpler to write (i.e. the inside of the block, the part that you as the programmer have to write, is simpler than what you had above).

But we are actually not done! It turns out that for this particular case, where we only want to transform the *values* of a [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html), there is actually an even more specialized operation available: [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```ruby
squares = original.transform_values do |value| 
  value ** 2
end
```

## Epilogue

One of the things programmers do most often is *iterate over collections*. Practically every program ever written in any programming language does this in some form or another. Therefore, it is very valuable to study the operations your particular programming language offers for doing this.

In Ruby, this means *studying the `Enumerable` mixin* as well as the additional methods provided by `Array` and `Hash`.

Also, study [`Enumerator`s](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html) and how to combine them.

But it is also very helpful to study the *history* of where these operations come from, which is mostly functional programming. If you understand the history of those operations, you will be able to quickly familiarize yourself with collection operations in many languages, since they all borrow from that same history, e.g. [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object), Python, [.NET LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1#extension-methods), [Java Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), [C++ STL algorithms](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.nonmodifying), [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence), and many more.

Comment: Fascinating article.

Comment: Thank you. I work very hard to make my reputation / word ratio as low as possible :-D

Comment: Wow man. I have a mathematical background myself, but honestly, I never thought of this in this particular way. Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: @mutantkeyboard: There are very deep connections between those recursion patterns and category theory. Google for papers from Meijer, Bird, Meertens, Wadler, or Blott as a starting point and go down a rabbit hole that gives you enough material to study for years!

Comment: damn @JörgWMittag, I want to give you my accepted answer now

Comment: After the first sentence it was clear this was going to be another Jörg W Mittag classic.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) method on hashes this way

```
original.transform_values { |v| v ** 2 }
 => {:one=>1, :two=>4, :three=>9}
```